# Prove that no order can be defined in the complex field that turns it into an ordered field.

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers, order-theory

I'm hoping to have my proof reviewed. Thanks in advance.

**Problem:**

> Prove that no order can be defined in the complex field that turns it into an ordered field. Hint: -1 is a square.

**Solution**

In the complex field we know that (0,0) = 0 and (1,0) = 1, and (0,1)$^2$ = $i^2$ = (-1,0).

Suppose there is some ordering on the complex field. 
Then either (-1,0) < (0,0) or (-1,0) > (0,0) or (-1,0) = (0,0).

> Previous result: for any x $\ne$ 0 in an ordered field that 
>   x$^2$ > 0 and that 1 > 0 since 1$^2$ = 1.

**Case 1:** (-1,0) < (0,0)

Then $i^2$ = (-1,0), but the square of any non zero number should be greater than 0. A contradiction.

**Case 2:** (-1,0) > (0,0)

Then the square of i satisfies the condition that squares are greater than 0, but we also have the ordered field property that:

> If x > 0 then -x < 0, and vice versa.

So, since (-1,0) > (0,0) then (1,0) < (0,0). But as we pointed out above, 1 > 0.

**Case 3:** (-1,0) = (0,0). 
This cannot be the case since (-1,0) does not act as an identity element under addition in the complex field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the proof is correct. But why do you represent complex numbers as pairs of real numbers? There's no need for that.

Comment: that is just how Rudin does it. i recognize and he explains they are equivalent.